# I am unable to bind a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ado

I am unable to bind a DropDownlist there is my code of Sqldatareader.
I am not getting any output. I want to display value from database and bind it.

```
try
    {

        SqlDataReader ds = obj.GetDataReader("Select Name, Emp_ID from 
EMP_Info where Emp_ID in (  select Emp_ID from EMP_Info where Name ='" + 
Session["AG_name"].ToString() + "' except select Emp_ID from RosterWeekly 
where  WeekStartDate  between '" + txtDate.Text + "' and '" + 
Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).AddDays(7).ToShortDateString() + "') Order 
By Name");


           txempid.DataSource = ds;
           txempid.DataValueField = "Emp_ID";
           txempid.DataTextField = "Name";


         txempid.DataBind();

        txempid.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Employee Name--", 
"0"));
       txempid.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(ds[0].ToString(), "1"));


  }
  catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }

// dropdownlist code

<asp:DropDownList  Height="35" Width="200" ID="txempid" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="txempid_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Why are you inserting Items when you have done data bind?

Comment: Also which event have you written this code in your page?

Comment: i am not inserting simply ,i want bind this dropdownlist..

Comment: Finding errors:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: You have an empty catch block .This is a terrible idea. Log the error at the very minimum. More likely you should remove the entire try/catch. You also need to be handling your [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects correctly.

Comment: @premmurmu  txempid.Items.Insert .. why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the datetime parameters in the string. I don't like txtDate.Text passed directly in the query.

I suggest you to put a couple parameters in the query and pass them as strong typed parameters (I suppose `obj` is an `SqlCommand` object):

```
var obj = new SqlCommand("Select Name, Emp_ID from 
EMP_Info where Emp_ID in (  select Emp_ID from EMP_Info where Name ='" + 
Session["AG_name"].ToString() + "' except select Emp_ID from RosterWeekly 
where  WeekStartDate  between @startDate and @endDate) Order 
By Name", conn);

var par1 = new SqlParameter();
par1.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
par1.Value = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);
par1.ParameterName = "@startDate";

var par2 = new SqlParameter();
par2.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
par2.Value = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text).AddDays(7);
par2.ParameterName = "@endDate";

obj.Parameters.Add(par1);
obj.Parameters.Add(par2);

SqlDataReader ds = obj.ExecuteReader();
```

I did not have time to try this out at runtime, so maybe something could need adjustments....

Comment: Thanks for suggestions . But there problem i am facing while binding the dropdownlist..Kindly check issue on binding..

Comment: It's because the query actually is executed at the DataBind moment: I think the error is query related and not databind related.